# Is there a way to start buffering video before playing it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I am trying to make an app that can play multiple videos at once. The goal is to record multiple music voices and then play them together. I am using the video_player plugin and each video has its own player. The problem is that when I start playing, it is not reliable when each player will start. So, I thought if I load the files before start playing this difference could be reduced. But I couldn't figure out how to do it and if it is possible to do. So, is there a way to load those files to reduce this difference? If there is another way to achieve my goal I would be glad to know. Thank you!

Comment: Is the files just voices (mp3) or actual video?

Comment: They are videos

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem where I want to control the exact moment the video starts playing.
For now, the best way seems to be (assuming you have a _controller constructed already)

- await _controller.initialize()
- await _controller.play()
- await _controller.pause()

After that, the video starts playing almost immediately. For my purposes it’s good enough but if you need to control this down to the millisecond for synchronization purposes it might not cut it.

You might also want to hide the video and mute it during those first calls.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. For my purposes, it didn't work.

Comment: @Filipe, did you manage to find something?